# I am trying to get my output div by submitting the form but it rapidly disappears?

Tags: php-5.3

i used //output div//outputcontent js function showDiv(){document.getElementById('divid').style.display='block'}

Comment: Can you show your html div code??

Comment: Show the related codes so that it can be answered.